# Windows bat file to copy specific column from text file and create new csv

Tags: batch-file

I have data in text file and I want to create bat file to copy specific data from each row and paste it into new csv.

> 58:58100300336,MCC,1822901002300008
>   58:58100300338,ROSS,1822901002300050

I want to only copy number after colon(:)

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
FOR /f "tokens=1-3 delims=:" %%a IN (transact.txt) DO (
 ECHO(%%a
)
)>new.csv
GOTO :EOF
```

Output which I am expecting is

> 58100300336
>   58100300338

With this code I am getting output as 58:58100300336

Comment: Have you tried this single line [tag:batch-file] example: `@(For /F "UseBackTokens=2Delims=,:" %%A In ("transact.txt")Do @Echo(%%A)>"new.csv"`?

Comment: Well, your code and your (wrong) sample output seem not to match, I would expect `58` to be output only for either line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
FOR /f "tokens=1-3 delims=:," %%a IN (q57712099.txt) DO (
 ECHO(%%b
)
)>new.csv

TYPE new.csv

GOTO :EOF
```

This worked perfectly fine for me.

Note that `delims` is a *set of characters* so you need to set `:` and `,` as the delimiters. Specifying `delims` **overrides** the default delimiter set, which includes `,`.

`tokens` are assigned to the *metavariable* - `%%a` in this case - the lowest nominated to `%%`, the second lowest to `%%b` and so on.

The data line is interpreted as `any delimiter sequence` `token1` `any delimiter sequence` `token2` `any delimiter sequence` `token3` `any delimiter sequence` `token4` etc., hence you require the *second* token, assigned to `%%b`.

As for the single-line output, I suspect that you are feeding in a *nix file which has `<LF>` alone as a line-terminator, where Windows requires `<CR><LF>`